# multi wan with 1 LAN port

Tags: networking, home-networking, pfsense

so there's my situation , I have a pfsense router with 2 ports.

```
Port1 - WAN
Port2 - LAN
```

Port2 is connected to a switch.
There are also 2 other routers connected to the switch (let's call them routerB and routerC).

Pfsense Lan port has an IP of 192.168.1.250. That's what I am using as the gateway in my machine to connect to the internet.

```
RouterB has an IP of - 192.168.2.1
RouterC has an IP of - 192.168.3.1
```

I can use these IPs as default gateways to connect to the internet from my main machine as well.

So here's the question -
Is there any way to configure pfsense to use RouterB/routerC to access the internet.

So I could be using different internet connections from different machines over pfsense.

Thank you.

Comment: The configuration you describe is not a valid configuration but an improvisation. You should setup the network properly and then use pfsense load balancing. In theory, you could try doing this in a virtual manner but there are too many things that can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with specific options with pfsense, but generally, you're config *may* be invalid, but we need more info...

1) Is Router 'A' your only link to the Internet, or do Routers B and C also have separate ISP connections?

2) If Router B & C need Router A to get their internet connections, then I'm assuming that Routes B and C IP addresses you give are their individual LAN side IP's? (because if those are WAN side IP's for B & C then they're on different subnets).  Otherwise stated, are Routers B & C getting WAN IP's from Router A's LAN network?

Assuming:: Router A is the only Internet Link, Routers B & C are getting WAN IP's from Router A's LAN side Network...

If ^-above assumptions are correct, then it depends on if there are any physical cables in your fabric that will be carrying traffic from multiple networks,,, if so, then you need VLAN's and proper configuration of trunk lines and PVID's... if not meaning, you have physically separated your networks so individual cables only feed one specific network, then this configuration works simply by setting up your DHCP, NAT and Gateway settings so they cascade accordingly.

A schematic drawing of  your topology would be helpful.